# typeahead is not working in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i write a small html code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html(ng-app)><html><head><title>Express</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script><script src="/javascripts/customjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Weather Forecasting</h1>
<div ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl"><form><input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states| filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control"/>

</form></div></body></html>
```

and customjs.js file code is

```
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope, $http) {

  $scope.selected = undefined;
  $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
  // Any function returning a promise object can be used to load values asynchronously


}
```

but typeahead is not showing its autocomplete behaviour can anyone please tell why its not showing suggestions ??

Comment: seems good. Can you set up a plunkr or jsfiddle please

Comment: I have created plunker that is working example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example which is working [Plunker Example using typeahead](http://plnkr.co/edit/4c79Az4KqihuvhrWP969?p=preview)

You need to inject `angular.module('sample', ['ui.bootstrap']);` in customjs.js

as well in html you need to initiate angular application with some name as you want to use ui.bootstrap module in which typeahead is one of it.

```
<html  ng-app="sample"><head><title>Express</title>
```

let me know if you still face the problem.